# why does razor make form with empty action?

Tags: asp.net-core

I create a form with razor to have specific controller and action with asp-controller and asp-action
but after razor render the page, I get form with empty action. I do not know why

```
<form asp-controller="PanelController" asp-action="AddCatAndSubAndBrand" method="post">
```

but result in html is

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

I put @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers in _viewImports

Comment: Did you try to omit the `Controller` suffix?

Comment: yes it works but if I want different Controller what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to drop the word Controller, if your controller class name is PanelController you just use "Panel". Its a convention.  Since it doesn't find the controller based on conventions it doesn't render the action.

```
<form asp-controller="Panel" asp-action="AddCatAndSubAndBrand" method="post">
```